# Replace one control with another

Tags: c#, asp.net

I  have the following code:

```
      <td>
         <center>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlDisplay" runat="server">
            <asp:ImageButton  runat="server" width="640" height="360" ID="imgButton" OnClick="ImageClick" />
            </asp:Panel> 
         </center> 
      </td>
```

Note that it is within a Panel 
Based one some validation after the button is clicked, I like to replace the button with a YouTube video:

I have done the following but the video shows below the Image I wanted to replace the button completely with the video:

```
     pnlDisplay.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<iframe width='640'  height='360' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/ZtcptQruWDg' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"));
```

Note I like a server side solution as I need to some validations.

Comment: set up two panels. One for each control, and then you can swap out the two by changing their visibility.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't care about the button being there at all, then before you call the pnlDisplay.Controls.Add, just do:

```
 pnlDisplay.Controls.Clear();
```